# 'cv': a namespace with this name does not exist while building (VS 2015, OpenCV 3.2)

Tags: c++, visual-studio, opencv

While building a simple OpenCV app in VS2015 I am getting error `'cv': a namespace with this name does not exist while building` while I believe I did all the required steps to configure OpenCV for VS (using this article as reference http://opencv-srf.blogspot.com/2013/05/installing-configuring-opencv-with-vs.html)

Beginning of the class is very simple

```
#include "opencv2/imgcodecs.hpp"
#include "opencv2/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/stitching.hpp"
#include "opencv2/core/core.hpp"
#include "stdafx.h"

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;
```

Since Visual Studio doesn't throw any errors on #include I assume the configuration in the C/C++ -> General -> Additional Include Directories is correct.

In Linker -> General -> Additional Library Dependencies I have the `opencv\build\x64\vc14\build\lib` folder added.

In Linker -> Input -> Additional Dependencies I have the following two libs:

```
opencv_world320.lib
opencv_world320d.lib
```

There is nothing else in this folder. Folder `opencv/build/x64/vc14/bin` is added to PATH.

Any suggestions what to check/change is appreciated :)

Comment: Sure, you included the headers correctly? Double check it, there should be the source of error.

Comment: After replacing#include "opencv2/core/core.hpp" with #include "opencv2/opencv.hpp"' I get warning  "#include "opencv2/opencv.hpp"': skipped when looking for precompiled header use". Also there is a ton of errors related to xtr1common...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I had this problem as well, and the solution was maddeningly simple:

**The #include "stdafx.h" must be the first #include.**

The example that the OpenCV folks provide does not mention this, even when they're providing an example for doing this specifically with visual studio.

Comment: it was same for me and that helped me. Thanks. i can't believe solution is that simple.i hate c++

Comment: That makes me mad when it's something dumb like this.  This is why people hate programming because of the dumb little things that aren't obvious.  Thanks for the tip now my code compiles.

Comment: can not open source file #include "stdafx.h" in visual studio 2019 :(